# css-loader, style-loader and typescript

Tags: typescript, webpack, webpack-style-loader, css-loader

I'm currently importing my CSS files composing css-loader and style-loader.

This is how the import looks like
`import './styles/index.scss';`

And the classNames are just strings.

I'm converting my code to TypeScript and I'm wondering if this set up is compatible with the language. Does anyone know how to make it work?

Comment: yes, it is compatible

Comment: @PlayMa256 do you have a snippet with an example?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is compatible with typescript.

```
import './styles.styl';

export interface TextProps {
    text: string;
}

const Text: React.SFC<TextProps> = ({
    text: string
}) => {
    return (
        <h1>{text}</h1>
    )
};

export default Text;
```